# How to hold copied Content using javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

TO be more specific I want the selected(copied) content(be it any where from browser or notepad..).A person can copy text from  anywhere and when he clicks in my application , can i get that selected(copied) content?IS it possible?If yes how?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to capture content the user *pastes*; they're effectively giving you permission to see that content. But you can't just view the clipboard whenever you feel like it. You'd be able to steal passwords and bank account details and other private information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html').on('paste', function(e){ // will trigger on paste in your page
    var clipBoard  = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');             
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You should see this. May be it will be helpful

http://harttle.com/2015/05/30/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript.html